# Table with unique columns only

Tags: mysql

For example, if I have these tables:

```
tblWeekday:
  id: int, PRIMARY
  weekday: char(3), UNIQUE
tblClass
  id: int, PRIMARY
  class_name: varchar(256), UNIQUE
```

with `weeekday` and `class_name` are guaranteed to be unique, and their values are used many times in the database. Does creating tables like this have any benefit or it's just a stupid design which will lead to memory being eaten up?

Comment: It's not a bad design decision if your business logic requires that these columns be unique.

Comment: The class table is fine, but the weekday table is probably redundant

Comment: @Strawberry Can you explain it clearer? Is it because the size of an `int` is greater than size of 3 `char`s?

Comment: No. It's because we know what the days of the week are. And so does MySQL. And they're not likely to change any time soon.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you very much!